# Javascript Regex to remove numbers from the start of a word.

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to clean up text and it's formatted like this:

1In the

12The answer

6अनाथ

Title

5-16These are

I want to remove any numbers and dashes anytime they are on the front of a word but am failing. 
This is close and works in the first two cases:

```
str.replace(/^[^A-Z]*/,"")
```

but when the language changes like the third case it removes everything.

The last case has a line break but this didn't work:

```
.replace(/^[^\r\n|\r|\n^A-Z]*/,"")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do:

```
str.replace(/^[-\d\s]*/,"")
```

Live code: http://regexr.com/38kkk

Explanation:

- `-` is literal dash. Note that if it is to be placed as a literal character inside `[]` , it should be placed right after `[`.
- `\d` stands for digits
- `\s` stands for white space characters (spaces, tabs, new lines)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want replace decimal digits and hyphens then just include those in your character class:

```
str.replace(/^[\d-]*/,"")
```

If you'd also like to remove all whitespace (including line breaks), try this:

```
str.replace(/^[\d\s-]*/,"")
```